# Windows Server 2012r2 virtualized domain controller

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, domain, controller

My work environment contain a single forest with two domains DomainA and DomainB.

DomainA contain the following:

DC01 holds all FSMO roles for the domain and forest, Global catalog and is forest root
DC02 is Global catalog

DomainB
DC03 is hosting FSMO roles for the domain
DC04 is global catalog

All above domain controllers are virtualized and all running on w2k12r2 on two hyper-v nodes as follows:

HV01 Hosts:
DC01
DC03

HV02 Hosts:
DC02
DC04

I have the following backup plans running as follows:

- HV01 and HV02 will be backed up on weekly basis the backup will be running on the hyper-V hosts
- All domain controllers will be backed up on daily basis the backup will be ran on the domain controller itself

My question is how I should restore those backups for forest recovery on domain recovery?

When I try to restore them using full system recovery the domain controllers will stop replicating?

Any help or idea ?

Shad

Comment: Are you restoring the Hyper-V backup or the domain controller system state backup?

Comment: Hyper-V backup  please ?

Comment: Are you backing up your individual virtual machines like this?  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2013/02/18/windows-backup-and-hyper-v-in-server-2012.aspx

Comment: that's exactly what I'm doing , but using command line not GUI I think both are the same 
at the end I will be havening the entire hyper-v and all its VM's

Comment: Are you restoring the individual virtual machines, or the host?

Comment: I would like to test both scenarios :
individual VMs and the entire Hyper-V host I case of hardware failure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makle backup/restore from Hyper-V and do not bother about anything special - Hyper-V takes care of versioning and replication in this case. New functionality in 2012 R2 ;)

Comment: Many thanks for your Quick replay:
how about the restoration ?
I have tried the hyper V backup again it didn't work so well ?
any idea ?

Comment: Yeah. "It did not work so well" means what? Hyper-V level restore works like a charm here.... that said, I use DPM for backing up the complete infrastructure.